# Trying to list pictures from a customView adapter

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-custom-view, custom-adapter

I'm trying to grab data from imdb and display the relevant pictures with the title and year adjacent to it. Have managed to display title and year, but when trying to display altogether, app crashes at search.

This is my results class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

    String keyword = getIntent().getExtras().getString("movieTitle");
    keyword = keyword.replaceAll("\\s", "+");

    FilmDatabase db = new FilmDatabase(this);


    String jsonResult = db.getResult(keyword);

    if (jsonResult == null){
        jsonResult = runSearch(keyword);
        db.insertData(keyword, jsonResult);
    }
    ArrayList<Film> searchResults = getValuesFromJSON(jsonResult);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);





    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(ResultsActivity.this, searchResults);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    final Button Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Back);

    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    }





private String runSearch(String keyword){
    String jsonResult = null;


    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + keyword);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream input = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
        jsonResult = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonResult;
}


private ArrayList<Film> getValuesFromJSON(String jsonResult){

    ArrayList<Film> results = new ArrayList<Film>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Search");
        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Film film = new Film(result);
            results = film.fromJson(jsonArray);

        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return results;
}
}`
```

This is my custom adapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Film> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Film> results) {
    super(context,0, results);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    LayoutInflater filmInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = filmInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    Film film = getItem(position);
    TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    textView.setText(film.title + " - Year: " + film.year);
    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) imageView).execute(film.poster);


    return customView;

}




private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
}
```

this is my film database class

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Film {
public String title;
public String year;
public String poster;


public Film(JSONObject object){
    try{
        this.title = object.getString("Title");
        this.year = object.getString("Year");
        this.poster = object.getString("Poster");
    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static ArrayList<Film> fromJson(JSONArray jsonArray){
    ArrayList<Film> films = new ArrayList<Film>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        try{
            films.add(new Film(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)));
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return films;
}
}
```

This is my custom_row xml layout file

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

full crash logs
    11-28 18:17:58.607 1555-1555/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
11-28 18:17:58.612 951-1016/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
11-28 18:17:58.612 1555-2512/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-28 18:17:58.621 1555-1555/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad71cd20, tid 1555
11-28 18:17:58.657 1555-2512/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad71ce00, tid 2512
11-28 18:17:58.671 1555-2512/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-28 18:17:58.723 1555-2512/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-28 18:17:58.723 1555-2512/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad6faa80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-28 18:18:02.244 1299-1623/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes/.ResultsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10058 on display 0
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes, PID: 2494
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:378)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:30)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-28 18:18:02.326 2494-2494/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-28 18:18:02.334 1299-1636/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes/.ResultsActivity
11-28 18:18:02.344 1299-1636/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes/.SearchActivity
11-28 18:18:02.418 1299-1807/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-28 18:18:02.453 1299-1807/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-28 18:18:02.453 1299-1807/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9c9dabc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-28 18:18:02.860 1299-1313/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{733fd5 u0 uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes/.ResultsActivity t31 f}
11-28 18:18:03.363 1299-1314/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 18:18:03.505 2419-2437/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-28 18:18:03.505 2419-2437/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa27d99a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-28 18:18:04.752 2494-2494/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2494 SIG: 9
11-28 18:18:04.756 1299-1329/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'f2bf72e uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes/uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes.SearchActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
11-28 18:18:04.756 1299-1329/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f2bf72e uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes/uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes.SearchActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-28 18:18:04.756 1299-1329/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'fb50451 uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes/uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes.ResultsActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
11-28 18:18:04.756 1299-1329/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'fb50451 uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes/uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes.ResultsActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-28 18:18:04.757 1299-1310/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{fb50451 u0 uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes/uk.ac.city.acnh550.searchitunes.ResultsActivity}

Comment: show full crash logs

Comment: is your custom_row syntax correct? Please provide full layout :)  

I think that might be a problem. If you have wrong syntax It won't generate R files correctly so therefore you won't be able to inflate.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a syntax problem therefore it can't generate R file. 
Double check custom_row file.

P.S If you use Android Studio It will help you with syntax errors with is's suggestions. (And if you already use, invalidate caches and restart)

Comment: what do you mean by check file?

Comment: LinearLayout has not opening tag :)